# Determining a hex value from a lex parser

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, lex

I'm currently trying to parse a text file and find any hexadecimal numbers within it. If the hexadecimal number is incorrect I have it display as not number.

```
input:   

-0xA98F 
0XA98H
0x123 
0xabc

expected output:
-0xA98F valid
 0x123  valid
 0xabc  not valid
 0xA98H not valid
```

My problem is if I get something like 0xA98H it will output as 0xA98 and display as a number. My goal is to is to get my output like my example however i do no see any resolution to my problem.

```
  [-]?[0][x|X][0-9A-F]+ {cout << yytext << " Number" << endl; }
```

Comment: In short instead of displaying 0xA98 I want this value to be ignored and instead displayed as 0xA98H = not a number

Comment: Why did you create a new question instead of editing your original one. I would improve my answer to your previous question [lex parser not displaying hex correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592185/lex-parser-not-displaying-hex-correctly) when you would improve the question.

Comment: It is easy to modify the patterns that first number is matched and second none. However, this effort is worthless as long as I don't know 1. what else may occur in the input 2. what else has to be matched (or not). Please provide a (not too long) sample input and what output is expected.

Comment: The only thing that will occur in the input is various false/positive hex values. I edited my post for the input example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sample code accepts hex numbers according to requirements of OP:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

static bool error = false;
static string buffer;
%}

HEX "-"?"0"[xX][0-9A-F]+
EOL (\n|\r|\r\n)

%%

{HEX} { buffer += yytext; }
" " { /* ignore spaces */ }
. { buffer += yytext; error = true; }
{EOL}+ {
  cout << buffer << '\t' << (error ? "not valid" : "valid") << endl;
  buffer.clear();
  error = false;
}

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) { return yylex(); }

int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

Compiled with flex and g++ and tested on cygwin:

```
$ flex -otest-hex.cc test-hex.l ; g++ -o test-hex test-hex.cc

$ echo '-0xA98F                                              
> 0XA98H
> 0x123
> 0xabc
>' | ./test-hex
-0xA98F valid
0XA98H  not valid
0x123   valid
0xabc   not valid

$
```

Spaces and empty lines are ignored.

`(\n|\r|\r\n)` denotes a pattern to match Unix-like line-endings, MacOS-like line-endings, and DOS/Windows-like line-endings (in this order).

Comment: i was also curious would this code ignore other numbers such as decimals and integers.

Comment: @sippycup It would/should due to the `"0"[xX]` part in the pattern. The following rules apply in the flex generated scanner: Patterns must match completely to match a text. If multiple patterns match then the longest match wins. If multiple patterns match equal length of text then the first rule wins. (The rest you find in `man flex`, `info flex`, or [Flex Manual](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex-2.5.4/html_mono/flex.html).